# Difference between honor, verified, audit and staff in openedx

Tags: openedx

Can anyone explain to me the difference between each user type (**honor**, **verified**, **audit** and **staff**) and they roles ? (a brief explanation of each user and what they can do).

I searched in the official documentation, but i found nothing !

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [Honor](http://edx.readthedocs.org/projects/edx-guide-for-students/en/latest/SFD_certificates.html?highlight=audit#honor-code-certificates)

Users are automatically enrolled as "honor". Honor code certificates are free of charge to all students and are available for all except a few specific courses.

An honor code certificate of achievement certifies that you have successfully completed a course, but does not verify your identity ([ref](https://www.edx.org/about/student-faq)).

### [Verified](http://edx.readthedocs.org/projects/edx-guide-for-students/en/latest/SFD_certificates.html?highlight=audit#verified-certificates)

You've verified your identity by using a webcam and an official ID from your country or region.

When you register for a course that offers a verified certificate you will be asked to submit your photo and a photo of an official ID through the use of a webcam. As your course progresses, you may be asked to re-verify your identity ([ref](https://www.edx.org/about/student-faq)).

### [Audit](https://www.edx.org/about/student-faq)

When you audit a course, or you take a course that doesn’t offer verified certificates, you’ll automatically receive an honor code certificate if you meet the requirements to pass the course.

If you audit a verified certificate course and pass, you will not receive a verified certificate, but you can participate in any or all activities and exams.

### [Staff](http://edx.readthedocs.org/projects/edx-guide-for-students/en/latest/sfd_dashboard_profile/SFD_dashboard_settings_profile.html#exploring-the-account-settings-page)

Course staff can access additional, optional information when a learner creates their account (such as the level of education completed) to find out more about the learners who enroll in their courses.

Some courses include a wiki, which provides a public forum for both students and course staff to access, share, and collaboratively edit information about the course ([ref](http://edx.readthedocs.org/projects/edx-guide-for-students/en/latest/SFD_wiki.html?highlight=staff)).

Comment: My absolute pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a related issue before, that I found some users are enrolled as audit and others are enrolled as honor in a course, and I searched a lot and read Drakes answer.

After a lot of research and investigation, I noticed that users enrollment can be related to course mode. I used to add honor mode to courses to django admin panel, so if a user enrolled in a course before I added honor mode, he will be enrolled as audit.

Just added this answer to indicate this link for future visitors.
And I'm now looking for a way to move audit students to honor, because, in the latest openedx release, they don't get certificates.

Edit: seems we found what we were looking for in:
theSite/admin/student/courseenrollment/